# Intermittent sqlexception timeout expired errors

Tags: sql-server-2005, timeout, iis-6, sqlexception

We have an app with around 200-400 users and once a day or every other day we get the dreaded sql exception:

"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding".

Once we get this then it happens several times for different users and then all users are stuck.  They can't perform any operations.

I don't have the full specs of the boxes right in front of me but we have:

- IIS and SQL Server running on separate boxes
- each box has 64gb of memory with multiple cores

We get nothing in the SQL server logs (as would be expected) and our application catches the sqlexception so we just see the timeout error there - on an UPDATE.   In the database we have only a few key tables.  The timeout happens on one of the tables where there is 30k of rows.  We have run profiler on these queries hitting the UI against a copy of production to get the size and made sure we have all of the right indexes (clustered/non-clustered).   In a local environment (smaller box, same size database) everything runs fast and to the users most of the day the system runs fast.  The exact same query (which had the timeout error in production) ran in less than a second.

We did change our command timeout from 30 seconds to 300 seconds (I know that 0 is unlimited and I guess we should use that, but it seems like that's just masking the real problem).

We had the profiler running in production, but unfortunately it wasn't fully enabled the last time it happened.  We are setting it up correctly now.

Any ideas on what this might be?

Comment: Do the timeout errors continually happen at a specific time (I.E., every morning at 10am)? Have you measured other performance counters like I/O wait times etc? Is there a backup or replication running which could be causing the problem?

Comment: It doesn't happen everyday but it does happen often late in the afternoon but not at the same time (e.g., 5pm one day, 6:30 another).  There's no backup or replication running - we checked on that.  How do we measure I/O wait times?